# How can I pipe jq output

Tags: json

I recently learned about an outstanding little tool, [jq](https://community.theforeman.org/t/friday-tip-of-the-day-use-jq-to-parse-json/7691) that allows you to pipe unformatted JSON output into it and then have that output reformatted and output to the screen in a very nicely formatted color-coded json layout. Eg:

```
echo '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq
```

I have found however, that I am unable to pipe the formatted results (from jq) into additional tools in my standard toolset, such as grep, sed, awk, etc. How can I make make this output pipe-able? Eg, this doesn't work:

```
'{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq | grep value
```

Comment: This seems to be a usage question on a general-purpose command-line tool. It seems more appropriate for Super User or Linux & Unix?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov - I posted here because DevOps seems significantly more likely to interact with JSON/REST and would benefit from 1) knowing about such a tool and 2) it's proper usage. I would categorize this as a *DevOps* command line tool, not general purpose.

Comment: My devs are far more familiar with these sorts of tools than I am, because they're *building APIs* and thus testing them constantly throughout the day.  While that will of course vary from company to company, I still think that curl/httpie/jq/etc. are just general-purpose programmer-y tools, not DevOps-related tools at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok tried to understand your problem exactly... This is what is happening:

```
$ echo '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq | grep value
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]
[rest of output is omitted for brevity]
```

The important thing to notice here is the usage line (emphasis is mine):

> Usage: jq [options] **<jq filter>** [file...]

The filter is not optional, if you don't give one, jq tries to parse the rest of the command line as its filter and throws an error. A workaround for your case here is:

```
$ echo '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq '.' | grep value
  "value": "New",
```

which indeed greps the "value" line as the filter passed is '.' - this just pretty prints the json content, but that's far from the best use of jq. If you wish to get only this line it would be better do:

```
$ echo '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq '.value'
"New"
```

If you wish to get the output without quotes then you can add add `-r` option to jq like so:

```
$ echo '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"}' | jq -r '.value'
New
```

from `jq --help`:

> -r     output raw strings, not JSON texts;

that's a little introduction to jq, that's probably not enough to solve your problem at all but as you didn't specify your problem I can't help more than that.

Comment: I think you may have been overthinking my problem. This was exactly the solution. An empty filter resolves the issue.